# DBSCAN with R including periodic boundary condition

Tags: r, dbscan

I am using the following statement in R programming langiuage for density based clustering in my 3D data analysis-

```
clusterstry <- dbscan(styrenexyz, 0.20, MinPts =20, method = "hybrid", showplot = 1, countmode = 1:10,100,1000)
```

However, this `epsilon (=20)` can not count the cases of periodic boundary condition.

Could someone please suggest how can I count the periodic boundary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own distance function, instead of using Euclidean distance.

Then you can easily implement your periodic boundary conditions. If you do a search there are examples of this with Python which may help you.

Alternately you can add an extra dimension to enforce periodic boundary conditions.

I would recommend doing the custom distance function instead the extra dimension to avoid any distortion. You can create a custom distance function in R by writing your own function then supplying the results the results to either `dbscan()` or `optics()`.

You'll notice that it accepts either a data matrix or a distance matrix. You can let R know that your object is a distance matrix with the function `as.dist()`. That's from the `stats` package.

Comment: This is what I found online- "You can add an extra dimension to enforce periodic boundary conditions. Say I wanted to use DBSCAN to extract points by their angle (theta) in polar coordinates. If I run DBSCAN on [theta], points 1 degree and 359 degrees would not be clustered together. However if I run DBSCAN on [sin(theta), cos(theta)], this solves the issue."
I tried with the angles and got error in the R programming.
Do you mind to elaborate a little more about what you meant by own distance function or using an extra dimension? I mean, how can I convert this Euclidean distance to count PBC

Comment: @Tuhin Sure. First I would recommend doing the custom distance function over the extra dimension to avoid any distortion. You can create a custom distance function in R by writing your own function then supplying the results the results to either `dbscan()` or `optics()`. You'll notice that it accepts either a data matrix *or* a distance matrix. You can let R know that your object is a distance matrix with the function `as.dist()`. That's from the `stats` package.